# How to remove dbo.AspNetUserClaims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application doesn't need the excessive  "Claims" functionality.It would be nice if these tables simlpy didn't get created in the database.
**My code in class ApplicationDbContext:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(c => c.Claims);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
    }
```

When I do this and attempt to register, I am getting the error message:

> The property 'Claims' on type 'ApplicationUser' is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method..

**Update:**

I used the code below and was removed IdentityUserClaim table, but I have a further problem with the removal of dependence ClaimsIdentity of ApplicationUser.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSFPE.png)

So can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Comment: hm, so if claims is excessive, why are you using ClaimsIdentity at all?

Comment: I would like to only remove from the database dbo.AspNetUserClaims because I do not use it, and leave the the rest of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I remove base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); line and i define keys which i needed manually.

then i use modelBuilder Ignore methods like yours.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); Dont forget to remove

        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        user.Ignore(u => u.Claims);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");

        var identityUserRole = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        identityUserRole.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });

        var identityUserLogin =  modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        identityUserLogin.HasKey(l => new {l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId});

        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
    }
```

[image]

as you can see above the IdentityUserClaim table not generated

Hope this could help to you. Thanks

Comment: Yes your code remove IdentityUserClaim but It is still the same error when I do this and attempt to register, I am getting the error:"The property 'Claims' on type 'ApplicationUser' is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method."

Comment: @k_dadun I guess. You need to override some methods which dependant ClaimsIdentity type. like ApplicationSignInManager class's GenerateUserIdentityAsync method it return Task<ClaimsIdentity>

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ayvaras . Maybe you know how   I have to override the methods depend on the type ClaimsIdentity?

Comment: @k_dadun sorry, i dont know directly but you can research about AspNet Identity OWIN authentications. you could find a article how you override. good luck.